# how to send intent.putExtra("getid",id) without displaying it in listview custom adapter?

Tags: android, listview, android-intent

i am receiving JSON string which contains id, and other string, now i want to pass id to another activity without displaying id in listview, id should be pass when i click specific icon then that icon's id should be pass from activity(A) to another actvity(B)

here is some my code just took relevant part

```
id = jsonObject.getString("id");
platformno = jsonObject.getString("platform");

listitem.add(new Latest_list(icon,name,date,id,platformno));
```

here above i no want to display id in listview

```
String id=Integer.toString(listitem.get(arg2).getNews_id());

Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Webview_news.class);
intent.putExtra("getid",id);

Toast.makeText(LatestNews.this, "platformno="+strPlatform+", id="+id, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: It's unclear what you are trying to achieve. Please show a [mcve]

Comment: i cleared now @cricket_007

Comment: Not really, though. You should include some code, otherwise you are only going to get some general guess at what you're looking for

Comment: Now i cleared question with some code. @cricket_007

Comment: Then what is the problem ?? and why code for example ?? Share your actual code of Activity and Adapter..!! with some click implemented as you are asking in your question with **i click specific icon then that icon's id**..!!

Comment: please come in chat now @jankigadhiya

Answer (score 0):

Your question is unclear. Depending on what type of value, here i have an example with String in an `ArrayList<String> arrList`.

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {
                // When clicked on an item, pass it to another activity
                Intent i = new Intent(this, AnotherActivity.class);
                i.putExtra("key", arrList.get(position));
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });
```

Comment: please can you come in chat? @Huy N